# Doesn't contain a definition for GetFromLocationAsync

Tags: c#, android, async-await

I am trying to execute the following code but an error occur :

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {


        var lat = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.latitude);
        var lon = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.longitude);
        var data = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.info1);
        var act = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.info2);
        var excep = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Excep);

        lat.Text = string.Format ("Latitude : {0:N5}", location.Latitude);
        lon.Text = string.Format ("Longitude : {0:N5}", location.Longitude);

        Geocoder geocode = new Geocoder (this);

        Task<Address> getAddressTask = geocode.GetFromLocationAsync (location.Latitude, location.Longitude, 5);
            IList<Address> addresses = await getAddressTask;
}
```

error CS0117 'Android.Locations.Geocoder' doesn't containt a definition for 'GetFromLocationAsync'

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved for GetFromLocationAsync() method, i was using an old version of mono android which is 4.6, updated to 4.8 and it showed up.

The method can be showed by using android.Locations class.

Thanks all for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/), I gather you have to add the necessary permissions, such as:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
```

For `Geocoder` and

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]
```

For `LocationServices`

Comment: Vitor Thanks for the reply, i tried so and opened the AssemblyInfo.cs and added those permissions, but nothing happened, i guess these permissions are not reachable in the AssemblyInfo.cs

Sorry i am new to android programming.

Comment: it looks like : [assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.Internet)]

and it shows an error : The name 'Manifest' doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Try with `Android.Manifest` instead of just `Manifest`

Comment: Yea it works, but still the GetFromLocationAsync() not visible!

Comment: Maybe try using `geocode.GetFromLocation` and just call the entire method from a background thread.

Comment: I did what you said and the application launch all good, but it lags too much and it says : Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I'll post this issue to my questions too.

Thanks for your help Vitor.